# Mysql order by extremely slow in joined query

Tags: mysql, performance

the query:

```
SELECT `files`.*, `file_status`.`downloaders` FROM `files` 
INNER JOIN `file_status` ON `files`.file_id = `file_status`.file_id
WHERE `files`.type`> 0 AND `files`.type` <= 2
ORDER BY `downloaders` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

the tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(35) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `upload_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_full` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `file_status` (
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `downloaders` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `complete` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_update` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`),
  KEY `downloaders` (`downloaders`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

this query executes for 5 SECONDS on 200k entries in the tables. the tables will have much more entries later so im afraid it will be a complete disaster..

if i remove the order by its executing normally.

is there any way to speed this up (other than moving the columns to the first table)?

EXPLAIN :

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key key_len     ref             rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      files       ALL     PRIMARY,type    NULL    NULL    NULL            256956  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      file_status eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4       x.files.file_id 1       NULL
```

Comment: if i use  `FORCE INDEX (type)` the query executes in 3 seconds, better but still unacceptable...

Comment: Just out of idle curiousity, what happens if you use MyISAM instead of InnoDB for `files`?

Comment: It`s completely a half-assed hack,but you can create a column in your first table with data from downloaders column and then create a composite index.

Comment: The explain shows it using the Primary key (which is file_id only) - that makes the join fast, but it cannot use that index for the order by and it can only use one index per table/join. Try adding another index with file_id and downloaders on the file_status table. If it works The explain should show it using both columns.

Comment: Also, you've lied to us about file_status. Not good. ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry how did i lie ? :p

Comment: That is NOT your table definition. At least, that's not ALL of it! The clue is an errant comma.

Comment: How many rows does this query return? How many different types are there? What are the types? Hint: If type and downloaders were in the same table and you had a multi-column index on (type, downloaders), and you picked just one type, both the WHERE and the ORDER BY could be satisfied by the index, but it will still only be used if the result set is small enough unless you use a covering index.

Comment: added proposed solution. Will there be any problem with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extremely hacky :

```
SELECT * FROM `files` AS x INNER JOIN (
      SELECT `file_id`, downloaders FROM `file_status` WHERE `file_id` IN (
         SELECT `file_id` FROM `files` WHERE `type`>0 AND `type`<=2
      ) ORDER BY `downloaders` DESC LIMIT 50
    ) as y ON x.`file_id` = y.`file_id`
INNER JOIN `file_status` ON x.`file_id` = `file_status`.`file_id`
```

the first inner join is because otherwise mysql says it doesnt support LIMIT in subquery

we use subquery for every table to make mysql use correct indexes (keys)

this executes instantly

Comment: Interesting,do you have the same results?

Comment: yes, as far as i tested, but i dont know how it will behave on really large datasets, so far i changed the `type`>0 AND `type`<=2 to `type`<100 (included all 200k results) and it works perfectly

Comment: i see a possibly wrong order of the result (in some cases) that can be fixed by adding another order by on the outer query. shouldnt take any resources due to 50 rows.